# How to simplify $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^0 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^1 + \dots + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have a recurrence relation with a geometric series within it. I want to simplify the series to something more useful.

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^0 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^1 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \dots + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-2} + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$

Some notes I am looking at suggest it can be simplified to:

$$\begin{align}
&= \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n - 1}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) - 1} \\
&= 2\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n - 1\right) \\
&= 2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n - 2
\end{align}$$

I'm a bit lost here. How was this answer approached specifically the first simplification and the second? The third is trivial algebra, I'm just unsure of the first two.

Comment: There’s a formula for the sum of a geometric series

Comment: @J.W.Tanner this one? $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$? This would suggest it is then $\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{1-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$.

Comment: $1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n = \frac {a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$ whenever $a \ne 1$.  That's a formula you should know and love.  And for the second $\frac 32 - 1 = \frac 12$ so $\frac {(\frac 32)^n - 1}{\frac 32 -1} = \frac {(\frac 23)^n-1}{\frac 12} = 2((\frac 23)^n-1)$.

Comment: "This would suggest it is then 1−(32)n1−(32)"  Same thing:  $\frac {1-M}{1-K}= \frac {-(M-1)}{-(K-1)} = \frac {M-1}{K-1}$.  those are so similar that must don't even notice which ones we use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n = \frac {a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$ whenever $a \ne 1$.  That's a formula you should know and love.[1]

So plug in $a = \frac 32$ (and replace $n$ and $n+1$ with $n-1$ and $n$).

And for the second $\frac 32 - 1 = \frac 12$ so $\frac {(\frac 32)^n - 1}{\frac 32 -1} = \frac {(\frac 23)^n-1}{\frac 12} = 2((\frac 23)^n-1)$.

=====

[1] $(a-1)(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n) = $

$(a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 + .......+a^{n+1})- (1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n)=$

$(a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 + .......) + a^{n+1} - 1 - (a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n)=$

$a^{n+1} - 1$.

So if $a\ne 1$ then $a-1\ne 0$ and we can divide both sides by $a-1$ to get

$(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + .......+a^n) =\frac {a^{n+1} - 1}{a-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

set
$$
S =\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{0}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}+\cdots+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}
$$
then
$$\frac{3}{2}S=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{3}+\cdots+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}$$
the difference between two equation is:
$$\frac{3}{2}S-S=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{0}$$
because all the interval term cancelled out.
thus, we have:
$$S=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}-1}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-1}$$
since $\frac{3}{2}-1=\frac{1}{2}$
the equation can be further simplified into:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
S=2\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}-1\right) \\
=2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}-2
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: compute
$$
(1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1})(1-q)
$$